# Post sent with no parameters

Tags: html, forms, http, post

I have got the following HTML code. I have no idea why the `POST` is sent with no parameters (I checked the parameters are not being sent with the firefox debugger):

```
<div class="modal fade"id="myModal"tabindex="-1"role="dialog"aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button"class="close"data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"id="myModalLabel">Add opinion</h4>
            </div>
            <form role="form" action="api/sendEntry" method="post">
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="user_message">The following: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_message" placeholder="In next...">
                        <label for="user_date">Until: </label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="user_date">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit"class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close </button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I suspect the nested input fields may have something to do with it, but I need to have them nested to have proper formatting.

Comment: you are missing the `name` variable in your input elements,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a `name` to your input fields. For example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
    id="user_message" name="user_message" placeholder="In next..." />
```

Form data is posted as name/value pairs. If you don't provide `name` attributes, nothing will be posted.

As a side note, I would also recommend you to correctly close your `input` tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal fade"id="myModal"tabindex="-1"role="dialog"aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button"class="close"data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"id="myModalLabel">Add opinion</h4>
            </div>
            <form role="form" action="api/sendEntry" method="post">
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="user_message">The following: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_message" placeholder="In next..." name="user_message">
                        <label for="user_date">Until: </label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="user_date" name="user_date">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit"class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close </button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Receive your data with `$_POST['user_date']` and `$_POST['user_message']`